# What does the Standard mean by "user-defined conversions are not considered", in bullet point (5.2.2.1) in paragraph §8.5.3/5 of the latest draft?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, c++17

§8.5.3[dcl.init.ref]/5 bullet point (5.2.2.1):

Emphases are mine

> If T1 or T2 is a class type and T1 is not reference-related to T2,
>   **user-defined conversions are considered** using the rules for copy-initialization of an object of type “cv1 T1” by userdefined
>   conversion (8.5, 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5); the program is ill-formed if the
>   corresponding non-reference copy-initialization would be ill-formed.
>   The result of the call to the conversion function, as described for
>   the non-reference copy-initialization, is then used to
>   direct-initialize the reference. For this direct-initialization,
>   **user-defined conversions are not considered**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an addendum to the standard to address an issue with the discarding of cv-qualifiers through indirect reference binding of a class with user-defined conversions.

The pertinent defect is [1571](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1571).

The example given was this:

```
class A {
public:
  operator volatile int &();
};
A a;

const int & ir1a = a.operator volatile int&(); // error!
const int & ir2a = a; // allowed! ir = a.operator volatile int&();
```

The first reference initialization is invalid, as it discards cv-qualifiers from the initializer expression. However, under the old rules, the second was valid, as only the cv-qualifiers on the converted object were considered, not those of the reference returned by the conversion operator.

I think your confusion arises from the two possible conversions. User-defined conversions are considered to see if they could copy-initialize a non-reference of `cv1 T1`, then the result of that conversion is used to direct-initialize the reference, for which user-defined conversions are not considered.

Comment: From what you're saying and this `is then used to direct-initialize the reference`, I'm reaching the conclusion that the result of the first conversion is not a temporary, to which the reference is bound to. But that doesn't sound OK to me!

Comment: @Belloc this part of the standard only applies to rvalue references and const lvalue references if that's what you mean.

Comment: Not exactly. Let me first say that I think your answer is correct (great answer by the way). I'm just trying to go a little bit further, and as far as I can tell, from this statement in (5.2.2.1), `is then used to **direct-initialize** the reference`, this seems to imply that there is no temporary that's being used, in this case, to which the reference is bound. I'm having some difficulty in accepting this.

Comment: @Belloc Oh, *direct-initialize* is a well-defined type of initialization, it doesn't mean there's no temporary involved. `int a = 42;` vs `int a {42};`. [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) is a good summary of direct initialization and I'd recommend reading that rather than parsing the labyrinthine standards passages on initialization.

Comment: I would then assume that the expression `except the last` in the last statement in paragraph §8.5.3/5,  `In all cases except the last (i.e., creating and initializing a temporary from the initializer expression), the reference is said to bind directly to the initializer expression.` refer to both bullet points  (5.2.2.1) and (5.2.2.2). Is that correct?

Comment: @Belloc Actually, it seems that (5.2.2.1) only pertains to user-defined conversions to reference types, as conversions to xvalues and prvalues are handled by (5.2.1.2). As such, that last statement would only apply to (5.2.2.2).

Comment: So, you are saying the 2nd line would use `operator volatile int&()` to create a temporary, then store a reference to it, under C++11?  Or would it do something else?

Comment: Yes, CWG1571 changed the wording there, but both the before and the after version disallows user-defined conversions in the second step, so that looks like a drive-by fix.